# Managing code with C# Windows Forms

Tags: winforms

How can I split a Windows Forms code behind file into multiple files so it's more readable? If I have 20 buttons with 20 click_Button events, that one file is going to be bigger than I'd like it go be.

Windows Forms seem to be very fragile in that if I delete a button or a button_Click event from the code-behind file, the program won't compile, etc. It seems like in building a large Windows Forms app that it would be hard to manage. Deleting controls, renaming controls, and in general tweaking the program seems to cause problems. Any suggestions?

Here's the code behind file for  a form with nothing on it yet. How could I split this across multiple files?

```
namespace WindowsFormsApplication6
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }


    }
}
```

Comment: That sounds like a maintenance nightmare. I'd rather have one large file than 20 seperate files w/ a handler in each.  If you split it into 20 files, it's still going to be the same size, just broken out into 20 files.

Comment: Learn how to use the designer first before you do anything drastic.  And look around a bit at professional UIs, twenty buttons in one window isn't very common.

Answer (score 1):

You can just split any partial into multiple partials.

But why don't you group together some controls into one usercontrol. And place several usercontrols on your form.

You will probably benefit from some re-use as well.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the "partial" modifier. It allows you to spam code across multiple files. But please don't do it... I'd suggest you rethink the reasons why you want to do this. As is commented, this is a nightmare for maintenance. A good workaround is to work with user controls.